# Issues Installing Foundation 5?

Tags: ruby, git, node.js, sass, zurb-foundation

So I'm trying to make the switch from Bootstrap to Foundation , and I'm attempting to follow the instructions on [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) page (as I'm trying to install Foundation with Sass), but the instructions on the site are rather unclear to me - I've installed Git, Ruby and NodeJS but every time I get to the step

> foundation new MY_PROJECT

I keep getting the error "Can't find Git, you can install it from http://git-scm.com/downloads except I've already installed it (and reinstalled it, twice actually) and I have no idea what to do to fix it.  Perhaps someone could lay out the instructions from start to finish in more concrete terms so that I can understand?

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough, I reinstalled Git and found that you have to adjust Git's PATH option so that it runs Git from the Command Prompt (essentially, pick the second option on the "Adjusting your PATH environment" screen when installing Git).

Not entirely sure why I didn't realize that before, but it fixed the problem for me!

Comment: Thank you! Zurb used to document their install process so much more clearly.  Now that they've made it more complicated (in the amount of different technologies they're using) they've reduced the documentation to almost nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably some kind of path issue.

You could also run Git Bash that was installed when you installed Git and then execute the `foundation new MY_PROJECT` command from there. It worked for me :)